# How to update my gatsby and its dependences

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, graphql

I'm new on React and I'm trying to update my gatsby and its dependences but is not working.
On the terminal I have put `npm outdated` and I got this below.

```
Package                    Current   Wanted  Latest  Location                                Depended by
gatsby                      2.32.4   2.32.9   3.0.0  node_modules/gatsby                     form-gatsby
gatsby-plugin-sass           3.2.0    3.2.0   4.0.0  node_modules/gatsby-plugin-sass         form-gatsby
gatsby-source-filesystem    2.11.1   2.11.1   3.0.0  node_modules/gatsby-source-filesystem   form-gatsby
gatsby-transformer-remark   2.16.1   2.16.1   3.0.0  node_modules/gatsby-transformer-remark  form-gatsby
react                      16.13.1  16.14.0  17.0.1  node_modules/react                      form-gatsby
react-dom                  16.13.1  16.14.0  17.0.1  node_modules/react-dom                  form-gatsby
```

When I tryind to run this: `npm update` I got this error below.

```
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: graphql@15.5.0
npm WARN node_modules/graphql
npm WARN   graphql@"^15.4.0" from gatsby@3.0.0
npm WARN   node_modules/gatsby
npm WARN     gatsby@"3.0.0" from the root project
npm WARN     6 more (gatsby-plugin-image, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer graphql@"^14.4.1" from express-graphql@0.9.0
npm WARN node_modules/express-graphql
npm WARN   express-graphql@"^0.9.0" from gatsby@3.0.0
npm WARN   node_modules/gatsby
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Found: gatsby@3.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/gatsby
npm ERR!   gatsby@"3.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer gatsby@"^3.0.0-next.0" from gatsby-plugin-image@1.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/gatsby-plugin-image
npm ERR!     gatsby-plugin-image@"^1.0.0" from gatsby-source-contentful@5.0.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/gatsby-source-contentful
npm ERR!       gatsby-source-contentful@"^5.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   5 more (babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer gatsby@"^2.0.0" from gatsby-plugin-sass@3.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/gatsby-plugin-sass
user@Users-MacBook-Pro form-gatsby % npm update
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: gatsby-starter-hello-world@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: gatsby@2.32.9
npm ERR! node_modules/gatsby
npm ERR!   gatsby@"^2.26.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer gatsby@"^3.0.0-next.0" from gatsby-plugin-sharp@3.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/gatsby-plugin-sharp
npm ERR!   gatsby-plugin-sharp@"^3.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/user/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2021-03-02T23_15_17_390Z-debug.log
```

I have tried to run `npm install --force gatsby@3.0.0`, but the same didn't work.

Do you guys any way I can update this?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to run `npm install gatsby@latest`
And only after that run `npm outdated`

Comment: Thanks so much! actually jsut worked when I did `npm install gatsby@latest --legacy--peer-deps`

Answer (score 0):

It means the version you are trying to update to has been found

```
npm ERR!   gatsby@"3.0.0" from the root project
```

Run gatsby -v to see if version is up to date

Answer (score 0):

For me simply `yarn upgrade` worked.